# NodeJS server socket - read client msg server.on('data')

Tags: node.js, sockets

I found these two links about **clinet/server socket programming** in NodeJS:
[TCP Example](https://gist.github.com/tedmiston/5935757) &
[NetJS](https://gist.github.com/sid24rane/2b10b8f4b2f814bd0851d861d3515a10);
 So i configured my micro server like this:

```
const SOCKETServer = net.createServer((socket) => {
socket.write('Server is listening!\r\n');
socket.pipe(socket);
});
SOCKETServer.on('data', (data) => {
     console.log('CLIENT: ' + data.toString());
});
SOCKETServer.listen(5000, '127.0.0.1');
```

and also my client like this:

```
const net = require('net');
const client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(5000, '127.0.0.1', () => {
    setTimeout(sender, 1500, null);
});
client.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('SERVER: ' + data);
});
let sender = () => {
    client.write('Hello Server\r\n');
    setTimeout(sender, 1500, null);
};
```

The code works fine and i can get data from **server** in **client**. I also can send data to **server** from **client** and i can read and see its feedback in client cause of `socket.pipe(socket)`. The problem is i cannot read anything in **data** event in **server**.
Here:

```
SOCKETServer.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('CLIENT: ' + data.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`net.Server` doesn't have `data` event.
You should read from incoming socket in `createServer`

```
const SOCKETServer = net.createServer((socket) => {
    socket.write('Server is listening!\r\n');

    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log('CLIENT:', data.toString());
    })

    socket.pipe(socket);
});
```